# Paginating date data in groups

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pagination, sql-order-by

I have a table that looks like this:

```
create (DATETIME) |   Message (TEXT)
=========================================
2013-08-05 9:00:00  "Hi there!"
2013-08-05 10:00:00 "Hi again!"
2013-08-07 14:00:00 "Hi from the future!"
```

I would like to be able to get all messages and group on `DATE(create)` so the messages are grouped by `2013-08-05`, `2013-08-07` and so on. This is easily done by an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY create
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to paginate by groups. For example, if I have 10 different dates, I would like to show all messages 5 date groups per page and paginate.

I have seen a lot of solutions for `LIMIT`ing the number of elements within a group, but haven't seen any solutions to `LIMIT` the number of groups.

I would basically like results that look like this:

If `LIMIT`ing to only show 1 group:

```
2013-08-05 9:00:00  "Hi there!"
2013-08-05 10:00:00 "Hi again!"
```

If `LIMIT`ing to show 2 groups:

```
2013-08-05 9:00:00  "Hi there!"
2013-08-05 10:00:00 "Hi again!"
2013-08-07 14:00:00 "Hi from the future!"
```

If `LIMIT`ing to show 1 group skipping the first one:

```
2013-08-07 14:00:00 "Hi from the future!"
```

How can this be achieved in SQL?

Comment: `I would like to be able to get all messages and group` => What do you mean by that? Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: @MostyMostacho Question updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearer with the example data :)

Query #1: 1 group counting from 0

```
SELECT m1.* FROM messages m1 JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT date(created) OnlyDate FROM messages
  ORDER BY OnlyDate
  LIMIT 0,1
) m2 ON date(m1.created) = OnlyDate;

|             CREATED |   MESSAGE |
|---------------------|-----------|
|  2013-08-05 9:00:00 | Hi there! |
| 2013-08-05 10:00:00 | Hi again! |
```

Query #2: 1 group counting from 1

```
SELECT m1.* FROM messages m1 JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT date(created) OnlyDate FROM messages
  ORDER BY OnlyDate
  LIMIT 1,1
) m2 ON date(m1.created) = OnlyDate

|             CREATED |             MESSAGE |
|---------------------|---------------------|
| 2013-08-07 14:00:00 | Hi from the future! |
```

You just handle the groups with the limit clause (first value is the starting group and second value is the offset from it). The query should be quite efficient too and is not hard to read either.

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c3f1/1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to calculate the group id and do the `limit` manually:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m join
     (select date(create) as createdate, count(*) as cnt, @rn := @rn + 1 as groupnum
      from messages m cross join (select @rn := 0) const
      group by date(create)
     ) md
     on date(m.create) = createdate
WHERE groupnum between 1 and 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

> *`LIMIT`ing to only show 1 group:*

```
SELECT created, message
  FROM messages m JOIN 
(
  SELECT MIN(created) min_created, MAX(created) max_created
    FROM
  (
    SELECT DATE(created) created
      FROM messages
     GROUP BY DATE(created)
     LIMIT 1 -- use LIMIT as you would normally do here
  ) z
) q
    ON m.created BETWEEN q.min_created AND q.max_created + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Output:

```
+---------------------+-----------+
| created             | message   |
+---------------------+-----------+
| 2013-08-05 9:00:00  | Hi there! |
| 2013-08-05 10:00:00 | Hi again! |
+---------------------+-----------+
```

> *`LIMIT`ing to show 1 group skipping the first one:*

```
SELECT  created, message
  FROM messages m JOIN 
(
  SELECT MIN(created) min_created, MAX(created) max_created
    FROM
  (
    SELECT DATE(created) created
      FROM messages
     GROUP BY DATE(created)
     LIMIT 1, 1 -- use LIMIT as you would normally do here
  ) z
) q
    ON m.created BETWEEN q.min_created AND q.max_created + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Output:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| created             | message             |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2013-08-07 14:00:00 | Hi from the future! |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Note:** Make sure that you have an index on `created` column

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8491d1/5)** demo